# Connection/Auth Cert Issue with OpenVPN

Tags: raspbian, vpn

I'm trying to build a VPN using a RaspberryPi 3.

I've been following this tutorial - http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing/ - and everything went smoothly.

Following that generated 5 keys:

- User1.3des.key
- User1.crt
- User1.csr
- User1.key
- User1.ovpn

When I try to VPN on mac with TunnelBrick but I'm using `User1.ovpn` but am getting some errors

```
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option 'root@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option 'total' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option '-rwxr-xr-x' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn

    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option 'root@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option 'root@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option 'total' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option '-rw-r--r--' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn

    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option 'root@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option 'VhKO/9+UtBQFQTHIDDENk12GmVTu3LW0vMx0a4xPSi81FG' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option 'gXddsYzkLXrPd1Vxdz6tUICsHU79NiHTEeZjRs2GG2I=' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Unknown option '-----END' found in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] Option '</cert>' was not terminated in /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] commandOptionsStatusForOpenvpnConfigurationAtPath:forTblk: returned 'error occurred' for /Users/my_user/Desktop/keys/User1.ovpn
    2017-03-09 10:31:45 Tunnelblick[51065] error status 0 returned from commandOptionsInConfigurationsAtPaths:
```

I'm not very familiar with this and wondering if the issue is due to me using the wrong keys, incorrect permissions on the key or that I screwed something up in configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The `.ovpn` file I had was no good. I did a `scp root@192.168.0.42:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/User1.ovpn ~/Desktop/` and it solved my issue

Comment: please mark you answer as accepted. Thanks for providing your solution